# Segoe UI Symbol Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Had anyone been able to release wpf applications to Windows 7 users and use this font? I have looked all over the place and can't see a solution.
I have downloaded the font family and placed as a resource in my project

```
FontFamily="/Helpdesk;component/Fonts/seguisym.ttf#Segoe UI Symbol"
```

This works on my computer however taking off the Segoe UI Symbol in the above gives me a square box.
Any help would be gratefully accepted.
Scott

Comment: it looks like there is an update for it; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094 and also there is a similar question to yours in here; http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/segoe-fonts-appear-as-boxes-after-kb2729094/dbafb137-211e-425e-93f8-d3259d3cee92?auth=1 it say it may related to conflicted with updates and another software.

Comment: The revision of that font in Windows 8, version 5.28, got a lot more added symbols, the kind that are used in Store apps.  You can't copy it without obtaining a license, Agfa Monotype owns it.  That might be difficult, I only see the Win7 version in their catalog.  Give them a call.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found a way to use the newer version of "Segoe UI Symbol" even when older version is installed (i.e. on Windows 7). The idea is to create a copy of the font file with a different name. This approach works also in ClickOnce installation and requires no bootstrapping.

It is posted on this link: [Embedded Font in WPF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893433/embedded-font-in-wpf-not-working/27911618)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the font `Segoe UI Symbol` is already part of the system it will not work correctly. But there is some tricks how to solve this issue.

1. Download your Segoe UI Symbol font or copy it from `C:\Windows\Fonts`;
2. Download the utility program [Typograf](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/);
3. Install, open utility, and "Change directory" for folder where you located your font.
4. Select this font in program and click "Properties", then rename it to something else (Segoe UI Dynamic Symbol as example);
5. Save your renamed font;
6. Import your font to Visual Studio and set next properties for this font "Build Action: Resource", "Copy to output directory: Copy if newer";
7. Check if in your `.csproj` file will be a such code:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
     <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\seguisym-dynamic.ttf">
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     </Resource>
   ```
8. Use reference to this resource in project like this:

`FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/<NameOfMyC#ProjectInSolution>;component/Resources/Fonts/seguisym.ttf#Segoe UI Dynamic Symbol"/>`

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27911618/21086817
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893567/21086817
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Before use it I would to recommend you to read this article:

- [Microsoft Font License](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq)